# stderr redirection by reading a file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stderr

I read content of the file into variable like this

```
var=$(<somefile)
```

But if the file doesn't exist I get accordingly an error message

```
bash: somefile: No such file or directory
```

Is it possible to redirect stderr to >/dev/null without using cat command?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, either use `cat`:

```
var=$( cat somefile 2>/dev/null )
```

or test for file existence first:

```
if [ -f somefile ]; then
    var=$(<somefile)
fi
```

To avoid the race condition in the last example (the file might theoretically disappear between the test and reading it):

```
if cp somefile myname 2>/dev/null; then
    var=$(<myname)
    rm -f myname
fi
```

---

The following will not work:

```
var=$(<somefile) 2>/dev/null
var=$(<somefile 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: This is the pettiest gripe, but the second fix has a race condition...

Comment: @MichaelHomer It has. The file might theoretically disappear between the test and reading it.  Another way would be to copy the file and read it if that succeeded, but the `cat` is probably best (and also portable).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
{ var=$(<somefile); } 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Hmm... yes, that would be best. Didn't we have this in an answer the other day (I can't find it)?

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, I couldn't find it either, but I'm pretty sure there's a recent dup too.